# Change a String inside a 2D array (matrix) in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix, char

I have a matrix of string, I initialize it and want to change a value inside of it, a value that is a user input. As far as I know, all my code is ok except the line when I try to add this value to te matrix (its the last line of code). Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINHAS 20
#define MAX_COLUNAS 10

void iniciarMatriz(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]);
void mostraMatriz(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]);
void inserir(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]);

void main(void) {
    char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS];

    iniciarMatriz(matriz);
    //mostraMatriz(matriz);

    inserir(matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]);
    mostraMatriz(matriz);
}

void iniciarMatriz(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]) {
    int i;//linhas
    int j;//colunas

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LINHAS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_COLUNAS; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void mostraMatriz(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]) {
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LINHAS; i++) {  //linhas
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_COLUNAS; j++) { //colunas
            printf("%i \t", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void inserir(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]) {
    char nome[10];
    int linha;
    int coluna;

    printf("Insira a string: \n");
    scanf("%s", nome);

    printf("Em que linha ?\n");
    scanf("%i", &linha);

    printf("Em que coluna ?\n");
    scanf("%i", &coluna);

    matriz[linha][coluna] = nome;
}
```

Comment: It's a character matrix! You can't insert a whole string at a row-column cell. And please post a sample input and expected output to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: So, how should I do it ? The input would be a string with no more then 10 characters. I dont get any output becuase the program crashes thanks to the last line of code.

Comment: please post a sample input and expected output. We will try to figure out where the problem is and modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler complain? Take the compiler's warnings serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass `matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]` to function `inserir()`:

- You are referring to an element beyond the limits of the matrix.
- `inserir()` expects a pointer to a matrix, not the value of en element. Simply write: `inserir(matriz);`

In function `inserir()`, you cannot initialize an element of the 2D `char` array with a complete string with `matriz[linha][coluna] = nome;`, you should instead copy the string after testing for limits:

```
void inserir(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]) {
    char nome[10];
    int linha;
    int coluna;

    printf("Insira a string: \n");
    scanf("%s", nome);

    printf("Em que linha ?\n");
    scanf("%i", &linha);

    printf("Em que coluna ?\n");
    scanf("%i", &coluna);

    if (linha < MAX_LINHAS) {
        for (int i = 0; nome[i] != '\0' && coluna < MAX_COLUNAS - 1; i++) {
            matriz[linha][coluna] = nome[i];
            coluna++;
        }
        if (coluna < MAX_COLUNA) {
            matriz[linha][coluna] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

`matriz` is a 2D array of `char`, you can use it to store characters or small integer values. Characters are small integer values. C uses static typing,  unlike in some other languages, you cannot store numbers and strings into an array interchangeably.  You currently print the array as numbers, if you store a string in a sequence of matrix cells, you will see the character values in the output of `mostraMatriz`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! But now, I insert a "String" and get an "Int" in the poisition I selected..

Comment: Ho yeah, my bad there with the integer in prinft. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer (which is correct), you can also dispense with `nome` in `inserir` and simply provide a pointer to `matriz[lihna]` to read the string directly into `matriz` (you need to limit the number of characters you accept, which is done by the loop in the other answer, or can be done with a *field width specifier* within `scanf` *format string*).

(personally, the loop allows the cleanest solution because it can accommodate changes to `MAX_LINHAS` and `MAX_COLUNAS` without having to also change the field width specifier.) But you should understand how both work and the advantages and shortcomings as well. Consider the following changes.

You can fully initialize `matriz` at the time of declaration:

```
char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS] = {{0}};
```

You can limit `mostraMatriz` to only operate on linhas within matriz that have content:

```
void mostraMatriz(char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]) {
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LINHAS; i++) {  //linhas
        if (*(matriz[i])) {
            printf ("matriz[%2d] : ", i);
            for (j = 0; j < MAX_COLUNAS && matriz[i][j]; j++) { //colunas
                printf("%i \t", matriz[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the example of `inserir` reading directly into `matriz` with the appropriate field width limitation:

```
void inserir (char matriz[MAX_LINHAS][MAX_COLUNAS]) {
    int linha;

    printf ("Em que linha ?\n"); /* validate linha */
    if (scanf ("%i", &linha) != 1 || linha >= MAX_LINHAS)
        return;

    printf ("Insira a string: \n");
    scanf ("%9s", matriz[linha]);
}
```

*note:* to accommodate whitespace in the string and control removal of the trailing newline from the input buffer, you are probably better served using `scanf ("%9[^\n]%*c", matriz[linha]);` Or, better yet, `fgets (matriz[linha], MAX_COLUNAS, stdin);` and then remove the trailing newline.

You should also change the return type of `inserir` to `int` (or anything fitting) to allow a check within the calling function of whether the call to `inserir` was successful.

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/matriz
Em que linha ?
3
Insira a string:
MyString
matriz[ 3] : 77         121     83      116     114     105     110     103
```

Think though both answers and let me know if you have further question.